# Cannot read component data within v-for scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm just new to Vue and I'm struggling with accessing my component data within a `v-for` scope. I get this error using the following code.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'whatever' of undefined
>       at eval

```
<template>
  <b-row class="my-1" v-for="field in inputFields" :key="field.key">
    <b-col>
      <b-form-input :type="field.type" :placeholder="this.whatever" required>
      </b-form-input> <!-- placeholder ERROR! -->
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
  <b-form-input :placeholder="this.whatever" required>
  </b-form-input> <!-- placeholder OK! -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      whatever: 'this is a string',
      userShouldSignup: false,
      parameters: {
        email: {
          label: 'Enter email',
          type: 'email',
          value: '',
        },
        password: {
          label: 'Enter password',
          type: 'password',
          value: '',
        },
        confirmPassword: {
          label: 'Confirm password',
          type: 'password',
          value: '',
        },
      },
    }
  },
  computed: {
    inputFields() {
      return this.userShouldSignup ? [
        this.parameters.email,
        this.parameters.password,
        this.parameters.confirmPassword,
      ] : [
        this.parameters.email,
        this.parameters.password,
      ];
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

How do I access my data variables within `v-for`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `:placeholder="this.whatever"` to `:placeholder="whatever"`. You don't need to use `this` there because Vue recognize that you want to access its data or computed values. This doesn't work because `this` in the loop is something else.

Look at this code snippet below (I had to change some things to reproduce your problem):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      whatever: 'this is a string',
      userShouldSignup: false,
      parameters: {
        email: {
          label: 'Enter email',
          type: 'email',
          value: '',
        },
        password: {
          label: 'Enter password',
          type: 'password',
          value: '',
        },
        confirmPassword: {
          label: 'Confirm password',
          type: 'password',
          value: '',
        },
      },
    }
  },
  computed: {
    inputFields() {
      return this.userShouldSignup ? [
        this.parameters.email,
        this.parameters.password,
        this.parameters.confirmPassword,
      ] : [
        this.parameters.email,
        this.parameters.password,
      ];
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="my-1" v-for="field in inputFields" :key="field.key">
    <div>
      <input type="text" :placeholder="whatever" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input :placeholder="whatever" required/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because "this" is pointing to "field" (loop), and the "field" doesn't have a "whatever" variable.

You just need to remove "this" keyword. You don't need it at all when access the variables from "data"